# Eclipse Package Explorer does not show all files in new Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, new-project, package-explorer

I've just set up Eclipse on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine:

I downloaded and installed:
  jdk-6u25-windows-x64.exe
  eclipse-java-helios-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip 
  swt-3.6.2-win32-win32-x86_64.zip
  Android SDK: installer_r11-windows.exe

I installed and updated all packages available from the Google repositories with the Android SDK and AVD manager.

Since I haven't programmed in Java for about ten years :), I went through the Eclipse "Hello world" exercises, and everything worked as advertised.

Then I tried going through the Android SDK "Hello, Android" exercise (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html).

I created an Android Project using the project wizard: File, New, Project, "Android Project", using Android 2.3.3 as the target and filling in just the essential fields: project, application, package and activity names.

The project is created, but:
- the Package Explorer only shows the "default.properties" file under the new project
- the Project Explorer additionally shows the ./bin and the three files under that
- All other project content is not displayed:
  -r ./assets/*, ./bin/com/*, ./gen/*, ./res/*, ./src/*

The directory structure is complete, and I *can* finish, compile and run the "Hello Android" exercise, but I have to open the source and xml files by dragging them onto Eclipse from the Windows explorer. Then things start to appear in the eclipse explorer panes.

Is this a bug in the 64-bit setup I've got? Error in my installation? (I doubt it, install was pretty straightforward).

I've found no mention of this kind of behavior in stackoverflow or searching the web and other fora.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem .What I did was :-

Right click the project name in the package explorer window and selected the option "Show Filtered Children".

Hope this helps.